# Azure Application Registry with Graph API produce different applications with RequestedAccessTokenVersion properties

Tags: azure-app-configuration

we've been using Azure graph API [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/graph-explorer-overview) to create new Azure applications for months, but since last week we found the new created applications contain different `RequestedAccessTokenVersion`  value from past months.
In the past months we've created thousands of applications, and all of them have "RequestedAccessTokenVersion " with 2,
[accessTokenAcceptedVersion:2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x5r0.png)
while since last week, there are several applications created, the value was null. [accessTokenAcceptedVersion:null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEVXE.png)
which will affect the access token generation.

We don't change any related code about the creation for the application.
Do you know what is happening?

We tried to find if we've ever changed the code, while we didn't.

Comment: If there is a change in behavior maybe raise a ticket with Microsoft. This says null is 1 (which is still different to 2)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reference-app-manifest#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute.

Comment: @Nick.Mc Yeah I've seen this wiki. While it worked with value 2 for months, and we didn't change the code, this just became to be null since last week.

Answer (score 0):

```
We don't change any related code about the creation for the application. Do you know what is happening?
```

As you did not change anything, the change must have happened on Microsofts end. The [API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1) still lists the expected return value to be:

```
...
    "api": {
        "requestedAccessTokenVersion": 2,
        "acceptMappedClaims": null,
        "knownClientApplications": [],
        "oauth2PermissionScopes": [],
        "preAuthorizedApplications": []
    },
...
```

Additionally, I could not find anything in the known limitations (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues/?search=application)

So I would recommend to create an issue / create a support ticket: [https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/~/overview](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/%7E/overview)

Comment: Thanks for the help! In fact we use Microsoft.Graph SDK to do the things, but I think they should be the same behavior. I will do more test on my side. If it's really an issue from Microsofts end, I will raise an ticket.

Comment: If you recently updated the library, please revert to a version where it last worked. If it still works, you know it's an issue with the library and must also be fixed by Microsoft. I consider this more likely than a change to graph API.